# C# Memory leak with Bitmap

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am writing a tile based game in C#. But I have run into a problem where when the application is in windowed mode my system memory oscillates about +-300MB, and in fullscreen it uses up all memory and throws the OutOfMemoryException.

I can't find any place where I forget the .Dispose() things that could cause this, as far as I know.

The closest I can pinpoint the problem is to a place where I .Clone() a Bitmap into a PictureBox.Image. This happens once every frame. I have the whole "world" rendered in memory, which is a Bitmap of around 2000x1000 pixels, from which I copy the part to be displayed on the screen.

I could attach the code, but since it is a lot I'll wait until it's clear that problem lies there, and not in the above method.

Thanks

EDIT: This is where I think the problem lies:

```
public Bitmap GetMap(Rectangle renderedArea)
    {
        if (renderedArea.Bottom > renderedMap.Height || renderedArea.Right > renderedMap.Width)
            return renderedMap.Clone(new Rectangle(0,0,renderedMap.Width,renderedMap.Height),renderedMap.PixelFormat);
        return renderedMap.Clone(renderedArea, renderedMap.PixelFormat);
    }

public void Render(Rectangle area)
    {      
        renderArea.Image = worldEditor.map.GetMap(area);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(renderArea.Image);

        PointF stringPoint = MouseInputEventHandler.CursorLocation.ToCoords(worldEditor.map.TileArray.TileSize,worldEditor.RENDER_START);
        g.DrawString(string.Format("{0},{1}", (int)stringPoint.X, (int)stringPoint.Y), new Font("Arial",15,FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Yellow, new PointF(6, 6));
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

From looking at related questions (which google didn't show me!) I found that adding this to the Render() function solves the problem:

```
if (renderArea.Image != null)
            renderArea.Image.Dispose();
```

However I would love to hear why that has to be disposed of aswell.

Comment: Without code, it will be hard to help ...

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's pretty clear what he's asking.

Comment: @MillieSmith The downvote may have came before the code was added

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't think it did, because when I clicked on the question, the code was already added and there were no votes.

Comment: @MillieSmith No clue then, its a pretty good question

Comment: Try [GC.Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) after .Clone() call. If this solves the problem, then you can fix it/ find new solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `Clone`, you create a *copy* of the object. So your *new* `Bitmap` object will eventually need to have `Dispose` called on it as well.

```
renderArea.Image = worldEditor.map.GetMap(area);
```

Reassigns the image without disposing, so you leak the old object. If you add the code from your post in, you clean up the object, fixing your issue.

A potentially clearer way of writing it would be:

```
Bitmap oldImage = renderArea.Image;
renderArea.Image = worldEditor.map.GetMap(area);

if (oldImage != null)
    oldImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that the old image would be overwritten by assinging the new image to it, which was obviously wrong.

Comment: @user2790895 yeah, references don't work like that :)

Comment: Yeah I know about references, but I mean the old image would not be referenced anymore when the new one takes it place and therefor shouldn't it be GarbageCollected?

Comment: @user2790895 It does, but `Bitmap` wraps a GDI bitmap, and needs to be manually disposed to release the massive un-managed object in a timely fashion.

Comment: The Bitmap should be disposed by GC anyway (in finalizer).

Comment: @Ondra As someone who has used `Bitmap` failing to manually dispose it is a sure-fire way to run out of memory. I'm not saying I like it, *its just the way it is*.

Comment: I agree. But anyway, the dispose is done automatically. So when the proces is running out of memory I would expect it will call the GC to get some. It should be very slow, but not fail.

Comment: @Ondra It may, or may not, depending on the whims of the GC :). Either way, waiting til your process to run out of memory for the Bitmap to be released sounds like a bad strategy to me :)